# Why isnt the whole shape extruding where i selected?

Tags: modeling

So im watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pYXqdWfaC0&ab_channel=RoBuilder go to 1:55 and when i press e to extrude its not working it doesnt extrude correctly. im just getting this weird glitched out thing and im getting really annoyed I cant fix this [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, most likely because you have overlapping duplicate vertices. Merge them by selecting all vertices with `A` and then pressing `M` and then selecting *Merge By Distance*. But it's impossible to tell the problem without more information or the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I think this is what you are looking for [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=KdW0aeZM" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/KdW0aeZM/)

Comment: Yeah I confirmed your model has duplicate vertices, do what I mentioned in my previous comment `A` `M` > *Merge By Distance*. And then make sure to remove those [Non Manifold faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you so much i just tried it and it works now! Thanks so much

Comment: Awesome! glad it worked out for you :) if you encounter further issues not related to this issue, then you probably will need to post another question. or you can edit and change the question and content.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie theres a 40 min cooldown on posting so maybe you can just tell me how to extrude inwards instead of down? Im jsut confused

Comment: Take note that when you press cancel after pressing `E` for extrude, it will create duplicate vertices so don't forget to always do `A`>`M`>*Merge By Distance*. Or undo the extrude with `Ctrl+Z`. Maybe you mean inset with `I`? then you can extrude inwards with `E` > `X or Y or Z` > `(a negative value)` or simply move your mouse around after pressing `E` it either moves inwards or outwards.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie if you go to 2:03 in the video it shows how he extrudes but when i press e it kinda goes Inward and Down not just Inward

Comment: @JammerTammer He's just bad at explaining. Where he says "E and then we'll extrude these inwards", he's not extruding inwards, but scaling down. So he presses E and before doing anything else (not yet confirming the extrude) but directly afterwards he presses S to scale the extruded faces down. By the way, E + S works okay on shapes where you scale the extrusion down to a median point, for more complex shapes this might not work and you should use Alt+E > Extrude Faces Along Normals.